# Brand new insinkerator soaked in water and hums without turning

Tags: garbage-disposal

Last weekend I had to fix my leaking insinkerator under the kitchen sink. I bought a new badger 5 from home depot. Due to the leakage before, I put a plastic wash basin right beneath the old insinkerator. Unfortunately during the installation of the new one, I had to use a lot of arm strength to hold the heavy new insinkerator up against the bottom of the sink, but my hand slipped and the new machine fell into the washbasin full of dirty water. When I finally got it installed and plugged in, and turned on the power switch, I only hear a humming sound but see no blade turning.

I tried pushing the reset button but it was inactive. Also tried turning mechanically with an Allen wrench to no rescue either; it did turn under external torque. The insinkerator got palpably heated up in a minute of turning it on. My question is, does that mean my insinkerator is completely broken due to short circuit? Would it recover after drying out in a few days? Can I qualify for warranty?

Comment: It is possible that it was simply defective from the manufacturer or maybe you damaged it by the drop; I recommend taking it back to HD for a replacement.

Comment: I don't think we can answer this (either if it will still work or is still under warranty). If you bought it at a big box store, you might get them to exchange it for another but I doubt Insinkerator itself would honor the warranty if it were damaged

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we cannot answer questions about warranties or unit functionality after damage

Comment: I realize this horse is already left the barn but there’s no reason to have a basin full of water underneath your new disposal when you’re installing it.  Uninstall the one you have put in a warm dry place and let it dry out for several days,  perhaps position a space heater to blow on it  then test it before trying to install it again.

Comment: @Machavity Is it still off topic if I remove the part about the warranty?

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean unfortunately it was ordered online. Thanks for your suggestion though

Comment: @JohnJiang Hmm... Try asking that one on [Meta](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/). The general consensus so far is we don't handle dead appliances. And in all honesty, if you dried the thing out and it still didn't work I'm not sure there's much else we could recommend

Comment: @Machavity thanks. For people in similar situations, I did let it dry out for 2 weeks and retry switching on, and it hummed for half a minute before dropping dead completely.